# How can I insert date range in mysql database using query?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have field in database table named date, and I want to insert into table date range from 2021-11-25 to 2021-11-30.
I do not know how to write query to insert dates into database each date in new row.
Like this:

1. 2021-11-25
2. 2021-11-26
3. 2021-11-27
4. 2021-11-28
5. 2021-11-29
6. 2021-11-30

Thanks for help...

Comment: Do you want to do an insert via SQL or via JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

> how to write query to insert dates into database each date in new row.

OK, given that the question is tagged with JPA I'm going to give you a JPA answer.

You create an entity like ...

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;
  DateTime myDate
}
```

And then you can create a data range list like this ..

```
 public static List<DateTime> getDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {

        List<DateTime> ret = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
        DateTime tmp = start;
        while(tmp.isBefore(end) || tmp.equals(end)) {
            ret.add(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.plusDays(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And then you create your entities from this list and insert them using a repository class.

Does this solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to generate your data, by defining a simple method:

```java
public List<LocalDate> dateRange(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
   return from.datesUntil(to).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then, you can store the data in your favorite way.

Using Spring Data JPA for example:

```java
// Your Entity
@Entity
public class DateEntity {

  public DateEntity(LocalDate localDate) {
     this.localDate = localDate;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private LocalDate localDate;
}

// Your Repository
@Repository
public interface DateEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<DateEntity, Long> {
}

// And the glue
List<DateEntity> dateEntities = dateRange(from, to).stream()
       .map(localDate -> new DateEntity(localDate))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

dateEntityRepository.saveAll(dateEntities);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this.

```
insert into table_name (....  , date_field) values 
select .... , selected_date from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```